# codeigniter route does not route as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes

in php word "list" is reserved so i had to use "listby" and create route.
According to CI User Guide I have created a route as follows:

```
$route['list'] = "listby";
```

It's routing perfectly the index function with url like "http://myserver.com/list" but does not route other functions i.e.. "http://myserver.com/list/uuid".

Here's contorller code:

```
class Listby extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        echo "index";
    }

    public function userid()
    {
        echo "userid";
    }

    public function uuid()
    {
        echo "uuid";
    }
}
```

Side note: with url like "http://myserver.com/listby/uuid" works fine.

Any clues where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$route['list/(:any)'] = "listby/$1";
```

Comment: Would be better without slash: `$route['list(:any)'] = "listby$1";`

Comment: It has reversed the result, now it's ok with every function but index.

Comment: Displays nothing but according to CI User Guide URI Routing it could be done without additional arguments http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html -> Example 1. But as i wrote in first post - it does not work.

Comment: @gutaker and Raidenace, both of you, see my comment above. I didn't post it for fun. Without slash it will work

Comment: @Vlakarados, I did it your way - doesn't work, tried Raidenace solution - doesn't work either.

Comment: So to summarize: I had errors like "...expecting T_FUNCTION...", I had a 404 Page... and at the end I gave up. Thanks for your hints guys.